# how to transform object in javascript using key value pair

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, arrayobject

I need some help manipulating an object.

What I have:

```
 actions: [
    { action_type: 'comment', value: '1' },
    { action_type: 'link_click', value: '5' },
    { action_type: 'post_reaction', value: '1' },
    { action_type: 'landing_page_view', value: '5' },
```

What I need:

```
actions: [
    { comment : 1 },
    { link_click : 5 },
    { post_reaction : 1 },
    { landing_page_view : 5 },
```

How can I achieve that?
Thanks in advance for any help! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use map

```js
const actions = [
    { action_type: 'comment', value: '1' },
    { action_type: 'link_click', value: '5' },
    { action_type: 'post_reaction', value: '1' },
    { action_type: 'landing_page_view', value: '5' }
]

console.log(actions.map((item)=> ({[item.action_type]: item.value})))
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
const newActions = actions.map((item)=> ({[item.action_type]: item.value}))
```

Answer (score 2):

If your prop names will not change you can use `array.map`, (`array.map` creates new array by transforming each element to new form):

```js
actions.map(a => ({[a.action_type]: a.value})
```

props to objects can be accessed with string indexes like `obj[myKey]`, so you can use `action[i].action_type` as a key for in new object.